# Making the plot x-y when I have F(x,y)=0 and including the uncertainties of x and y

Tags: python, plot

I solve the following function

```
F = [-a*cos(x+y)+sin(x) - cos(y)]-(-b*cos(x+y) +sin(x)+cos(y)) = 0
```

And I get the x,y by writing:

```
from sympy import plot_implicit, cos, sin, symbols, Eq
x, y = symbols('x y')


a = 4
b = 1
c = 0.25

F1 = plot_implicit(Eq([-a*cos(x+y)+sin(x) - cos(y)]-(-b*cos(x+y) +sin(x)+cos(y)), 0))
```

How can I add the uncertainties in this case, thus to make a plot on the x-y axis including the uncertainties of x,y? Knowing that

```
a = 4 +/- 0.5,
b = 1+/- 0.2,
c = 0.25 +- 0.01,
```

I repeated the previous strategy implementing (instead of only the central value) the central value plus the uncertainty of the quantities

```
from sympy import plot_implicit, cos, sin, symbols, Eq
x, y = symbols('x y')


a = 4 +/- 0.5
b = 1+/- 0.2
c = 0.25 +- 0.01


F1 = plot_implicit(Eq([- (a+error_a)*cos(x+y)+sin(x) - cos(y)]-(-(b+error_b)*cos(x+y) +sin(x)+cos(y)), 0))
```

And then again the same process for the case 'central value minus uncertainty'

Is this a correct way to deal with the uncertainties? Is there anything else that I can do?

I appreciate any help you can provide!